# Add namespace to WCF method

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, web-config

I have this WCF project I want to add 'tem' prefix to method not input like these lines XML code

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"> 
<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body>
<tem:FetchServiceInfoByBillId>
<USER_NAME>username</USER_NAME>
</tem:FetchServiceInfoByBillId>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the interface

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace ="")]
public interface IOnlineService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Error_code")]
  string FetchServiceInfoByBillId(string USER_NAMES);

}
```

and I get these XML with this interface

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"> 
<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body>
<FetchServiceInfoByBillId>
<USER_NAME>username</USER_NAME>
</FetchServiceInfoByBillId>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If I use `[ServiceContract]` instead of `[ServiceContract(Namespace ="")]` I get 'tem' before method and input but I just want it before the method name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of searching, I figure out the solution with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843620/how-can-i-specify-a-namespace-for-operationcontract-when-using-wcf). Also, it didn't because the client had problems with the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MessageInterceptor to customize the SOAP message or modify it.

This is sample code on the client:

```
     public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        MessageHeader header1 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testreply", "http://Test", "Test");
    request.Headers.Add(header1);
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserAgent", "http://User", "User1");
    reply.Headers.Add(header);
    return null;

    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public Type TargetContract => typeof(ServiceReference1.ICalculator);
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageLogger());
    }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

This is sample code on the service:

```
 public class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserAgent", "http://User", "User1");
        request.Headers.Add(header);
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        MessageHeader header1 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testreply", "http://Test", "Test");
        reply.Headers.Add(header1);
    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

To apply a message interceptor, you must add the CustomBehavior feature, You use a client-side interceptor to add it on the client's interface, and use a server-side message interceptor to add it to the server's interface.
[image]

Here is the reference: [IClientMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)   [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I added these classes but I don't see any differences. Also I add this code block on Add AddBindingParameters method : 
`foreach (OperationDescription  operation in contractDescription.Operations)
            {
                operation.DeclaringContract.Namespace = "temp";
            }`

Comment: Using this class to customize the message, you can customize the message header and message. Use this class to modify the soap message, you need to add the message you want to add, modify this part of the code: MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserAgent", "http://User", "User1");
    reply.Headers.Add(header);